# Ceiling Candleabra Bumped and Come Slightly Apart / Repair For?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

With a ladder, I bumped a ceiling candelabra I guess you would call it (4 lights and a fan on the unit).  The lights all still working but the metal part that connects to the center has become slightly disconnected and everything is hanging down slightly.  Like the wires are hanging down and the bottom disc looks like it is either unscrewed or otherwise not able to connect.  It looks stable, but I worry about the strain of the wires hanging down.

I will try to post a photo later.  But I am trying to figure out how to reconnect it?  It looks like everything can be screwed back in place but I couldn't get it and I wonder how the metal connected to the metal.  I cannot find a comparative part currently through Google to demonstrate.

** EDIT **
Photos included with two points of disconnection[image][image][image]

Comment: Useless until we see a  photo.

Comment: It looks like there's a threaded rod going all the way through.  Is the knob on the bottom, with the pull-cord going through, actually the nut that holds everything on?

Comment: @SimonB - That's what I thought.  But when I try to push everything up and screw, as it were, everything back in to place, the bottom part will not stay with the rest.  It is as if I would need to apply an adhesive, like a super glue, for it to stay in place. There do no appear to be any breakages which would present the bottom from attaching with the rest.  I have been trying and trying and trying without applying super glue, but it just won't stay.  The light still works, the only functionality concern is that the cord is only partially functional.